# ¿Como crear objetos usando el Scanner?

Tags: java, netbeans, poo, consola

Tengo una duda con respecto a como declarar y crear un objeto en java. 
Verán mas adelante mi código que trata de Estudiantes y cada estudiante tiene "n" materias, lo que quiero lograr es agregar algo como una terminal en donde desde la consola se puedan introducir datos del estudiante y desde la misma consola agregar materias con sus respectivas notas.
Aquí en esta clase van las calificaciones de la materia, del parcial 1,2 y el final, agregar practicos/ tareas es opcional y tambien quisiera ponerlo como opción en la terminal.

```
public class Estudiante {

private String nombre;
private Materia[] lista = new Materia[5];

public Estudiante(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public void addMateria(Materia m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
        if (lista[i] == null) {
            lista[i] = m;
            break;
        }
    }
}

public int getNotaMaxima() {
    int max = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
        Materia aux = lista[i];
        if (aux != null) {
            if (aux.getNotaFinal() > 0) {
            max = Math.max(aux.getNotaFinal(),max);
        }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("------------------------");
    System.out.println("La nota máxima de " + nombre + " es:");
    return max;

}

public int getNotaMinima() {
    int min = 100;

    for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
        Materia aux = lista[i];
        if (aux != null) {
            if(aux.getNotaFinal() != 0){
            min = Math.min(aux.getNotaFinal(), min);
        }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("------------------------");
    System.out.println("La nota mínima de " + nombre + " es:");
    return min;

}

public int getPromedio() {
    int cont = 0;
    int aux = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
        if (lista[i] != null) {
            aux = aux + lista[i].getNotaFinal();
            cont++;
        }
    }

    int res = aux/cont;
    return res;
}

public String showMaterias() {
    String texto = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.length && lista[i] != null; i++) {
        texto += lista[i].getNombre() + "--" + lista[i].getNotaFinal() + "\n";
    }
    return texto;
}
}

public class Materia {

private String nombre;
private int parcial1;
private int parcial2;
private int[] practicos = new int[20];
private int examen_final;



public Materia(String nombre, int parcial1, int parcial2, int examen_final) 
{
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.parcial1 = parcial1;
    this.parcial2 = parcial2;
    this.examen_final = examen_final;
}

public void addPractico(int nota) {
    for (int i = 0; i < practicos.length; i++) {
        if (practicos[i] == 0) {
            practicos[i] = nota;
            break;
        }

    }
}

public int getNotaPracticos() {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < practicos.length; i++) {
        total += practicos[i];
    }
    return total;
}

public int getNotaFinal() {
    int res =parcial1 + parcial2 + getNotaPracticos() + examen_final;
    return res;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getParcial1() {
    return parcial1;
}

public void setParcial1(int parcial1) {
    this.parcial1 = parcial1;
}

public int getParcial2() {
    return parcial2;
}

public void setParcial2(int parcial2) {
    this.parcial2 = parcial2;
}

public int getExamen_final() {
    return examen_final;
}

public void setExamen_final(int examen_final) {
    this.examen_final = examen_final;
}

}


public class Consola {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Materia pro2 = new Materia("Programacion II", 10, 15, 20);
    Materia base1 = new Materia("Base de Datos I", 8, 12, 21);
    Materia sistemas1 = new Materia("Sistemas Operativo I", 15, 8, 5);
    Materia calculo = new Materia("Calculo I", 10, 5, 4);

    Estudiante juan = new Estudiante("Juan Perez");
    juan.addMateria(pro2);
    juan.addMateria(base1);
    juan.addMateria(sistemas1);
    juan.addMateria(calculo);


    calculo.addPractico(7);
    calculo.addPractico(4);
    calculo.addPractico(8);

    sistemas1.addPractico(5);
    sistemas1.addPractico(4);
    sistemas1.addPractico(8);

    pro2.addPractico(5);
    pro2.addPractico(5);
    pro2.addPractico(7);
    pro2.addPractico(4);

    base1.addPractico(8);
    base1.addPractico(3);

    System.out.println("--------------------");

    System.out.println(juan.showMaterias());
    System.out.println(juan.getNotaMinima());
    System.out.println(juan.getNotaMaxima());
}
}
```

Soy estudiante y estoy aprendiendo lo que es POO, y tenía esa duda de  como podría hacer la terminal.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Quizas no pueda responder tu pregunta al 100% pero si te puedo mostrar 2 errores que tienes.

```
Materia pro2 = new Materia("Programacion II", 10, 15, 20);
Materia base1 = new Materia("Base de Datos I", 8, 12, 21);
Materia sistemas1 = new Materia("Sistemas Operativo I", 15, 8, 5);
Materia calculo = new Materia("Calculo I", 10, 5, 4);
```

En esta parte del codigo tengo que resaltar cuando en la primera casilla pones el nombre de la materia entre comillas te refieres a un dato de tipo String, pero en el siguiente cuando agregas una calificacion no tiene comillas por lo que el programa lo determinaria como tipo int ya que es un numero entero

Aqui el problema es que los arreglos no pueden admitir 2 tipos de variables (Al menos en Java no se puede) o tu arreglo es de tipo String o es solo de tipo int.

En este caso, yo te sugiero que no pongas el nombre de las materias, sino que te vayas solo por ingresar las calificaciones o bien crear 2 arreglos separados.

Otro punto que noto es que quieres que cada alumno tenga "n" cantidad de materias. Esto es imposible de hacer con los arreglos en Java, ya que no existe manera de redimensionar los arreglos. Aqui yo sugiero crear un arreglo de, por ejemplo, 100 casillas y solo llenar las que se vayan a usar restringiendo el ciclo for con una variable para i en vez de ponerle i<100.

```
int numMaterias;
for(int i=0; i<numMaterias; i++){ 
      /*
       * Para este caso la variable de tipo int numMaterias seria ingresada por el
       * usuario habiendole preguntado antes cuantas materias lleva el alumno y de 
       * esa forma el arreglo no recorre las 100 casillas.
       */
}
```